# Java: how to handle/parse incoming HTTP requests?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http

I would like to receive parameters via plain text and http requests. The data is coming in, but I'm stuck with processing it correctly.

Here is some pseudocode of what I would like to achieve:

```
// ...
String input = in.readLine();
if (HttpHelperClass.isValidHttpRequest(input)) {
    // process http request
    MyHttpRequest = HttpHelperClass.processInput(input);

    if (MyHttpRequest.isMethod(HTTP_METHOD_GET)) {
        String name = MyHttpRequest.getParameter('name');
        String response = HttpHelperClass.buildResponse("Hello " + name, 200);
        out.println(response);
   }
} else {
    // process plain text
}
```

Does Java have something like this out of the box or can anyone recommend anything?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [`UrlQuerySanitizer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/UrlQuerySanitizer.html). Use this to parse the URL and then call `getValue("param-name")` to get the desired parameter values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the `UrlQuerySanitizer` only covers URLs and their `GET` parameters. I need to process `POST` as well.